# npm problems with installing gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I have problems in my terminal when I want to install something with npm (gulp).
Please help, if you know something with it.

```
roman@MacBook-Pro-Roman advanced % npm
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/Roman'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:171:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:165:25)
```

Comment: try this -> npm cache clean

Comment: Also you might have to give access to npm at this location '/Roman'

Comment: @sudhee, when I type npm cache clean, I have the same error

Comment: @sudhee, if you have some link how to give the permissions pls comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you either have a file system that is set to read only. Possible due to some software/hardware issues or the permissions are not set correct for npm to write to the storage device.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer:

sudo npm config set prefix ~/npm